# EmberJs ember-animated-outlet not working

Tags: animation, ember.js

I'm trying to use ember animated outlet (found [here](https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet)) and, I can not for the life of me get it to work, I understand that instead of using `{{outlet}}` I need to use `{{animated-outlet}}` and use `{{link-to-aniamted}}` instead but it seems to be switching like normal. I also know that I need to include the js after the ember.js and also I am including the css file it comes with, so I'm kind of stumped on this. :( 
For my basic view, I'm using

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <div class='wrapper'>
        @include('includes.globals.header')
        <div class='content row' id='content'>
            {{animated-outlet}}
        </div>
        @include('includes.globals.footer')
        @include('includes.js.navigation')
    </div>
</script>
```

and my link looks like:

```
{{#link-to-animated 'index' animations="main:slideLeft"}} Home @{{/link-to-animated}}
```

So, is there something i'm missing? Do I need to add something in my app.js? IF you need more code or info, just ask and I will edit this question! Thanks a lot in advance! I'm new to ember, so please take it easy!

Comment: I am also trying to fix the same issue. No breakthrough yet

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify 'name' in the animated-outlet helper.

{{animated-outlet name="main"}}

The readme explains it: https://github.com/billysbilling/ember-animated-outlet/blob/master/README.md#use-animated-outlet-instead-of-outlet